The UV radiation values inside the dataset are too large
I am trying to make a website to check the UV intensity of various cities.
When I read the paper Two ultraviolet radiation datasets that cover China I had a doubt.

The UV radiation in Table 4 of the paper is too big (32766 indicates measurement errors, 9999 indicates the measurement does not satisfy the quality control principle).
For example, the UV radiation on "9 July 2015 12h" is 27.7 W/m², which convert to a UV index of 1108, far more than 11.
I use method from https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/7148/15283 and NOAA, which multiply by 40.
I download the observed UV radiation data from the original dataset, and found that a large number of data are well above normal.
I would like to know how to convert to UV index correctly.

I think your question is "How do I calculate the UV index from UV radiation?" - can you state what method have you used to convert UV radiation to UV index so someone can verify it?
